# passing parameters in url invoke in grail, jquery

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy

am a newbie to grails and JQuery as well,
I am having this issue with invoking a url, currently its invoked using  tag like this:

${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "employeeid")}

when this link is clicked the URL changes to /myapp/users/userEdit/"value of employeeid".
why does the employeeId get appended in the URL like that

In the controller userEdit action is defined as follows:

```
 def userEdit={
            if(params.id!=null && params.id.toString().trim().length()>0){
                log.info("Returning UserInstance whose employee Id: "+params.id)
                def userInstance= Users.findByEmployeeid(params.id.toString().trim());
                if (params.fromdate!=null && params.todate!=null && params.resourceId!=null)  {   
render(view:"actEdit",model:[userInstance:userInstance,fdate:params.fromdate,tdate:params.todate,resId:params.resourceId])   
                  }
                else {render(view:"actEdit",model:[userInstance:userInstance]) }
         } }
```

basically checking value of id and rendering the page.

Now I am trying to invoke the userEdit action from another page using jquery.ajax() call like this

```
function drillchart(empid){
var empid =empid
 jQuery.ajax({
               url: '/myapp/users/userEdit'+empid,
                data:{
               'fromdate':fromdate,
                'todate':todate,
                'resourceId':res_id
                },
                 dataType: 'html',
                 timeout: 10000,
     beforeSend: function() { jQuery('#userStatisticsDiv').html(/spinner.gif)},
     success: function(data) { window.location = myurl;}
                              });
```

The problem is the data parameters fromdate,todate, resourceId are not getting passed hence in the action its always going inside the else.

If I am not passing the empid directly in the url of the call, and put it as 'id':empid in the data section of the call it doesnt get forwarded properly.

I need to know how do I invoke the appropriate URL and pass all the parameters in the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. Check the end slash in the url parameter concatenation.
2. Don't use sigle colons in you variable names.

So it must be as follows:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: '/myapp/users/userEdit/'+empid,  //Check if the last slash is needed
   data:   {
             fromdate:fromdate,
             todate:todate,
             resourceId:res_id
           },
   dataType: 'html',
   timeout: 10000,
   beforeSend: function() { jQuery('#userStatisticsDiv').html(/spinner.gif)},
   success: function(data) { window.location = myurl;}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Right now I am just invoking a different action, copied userEdit into it and its working as temporary fix.. I want test more changes to make it one action eventually.